# output child terms of current custom taxonomy term with images

Tags: image, taxonomy, children

Just wondering if anyone can help with this - banging my head for days...

From a custom taxonomy page (taxonomy_genre.php), I need to output the child terms with images.

I'm using the 'Taxonomy Images' plugin to set the image.

Code below - thanks in advance if anyone can give me some pointers!

code #1 outputs all terms including parent terms.
code #2 outputs the correct terms but with no images

essentially I'm trying to amalgamate the two.

code #1:

```
     $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

$args = array(
                            'taxonomy'     => $current_term->taxonomy,
                            'child_of'     => $current_term->term_id,
                                'term_args'    => array(
                                'orderby'      => 'id',
                                'order'        => 'ASC',
                                'hierarchical' => 0,

                                ),

                            );

    $cats = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', $args );

foreach ($cats as $cat) {

echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($cat) . '" title="'. $cat->name .'">' ;
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $cat->image_id, 'detail' );
echo $cat->name ;
echo '</a></li>';
}
```

code #2

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$cats = wp_list_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'depth'  => 2,
    'title_li' => ''
    ));
foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
$catdesc = $cat->category_description;
echo '<li><a href="'. get_category_link($cat).'" title="'. $cat->cat_name .'">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $cat->image_id, 'detail' ) . $cat->cat_name . '</a></li>'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - used:

'parent' => $current_term->term_id,

instead of:

child_of => $current_term->term_id,